# Java8 For Each Loop Skip first Iteration

Tags: list, java-8

How can I write a code JAVA8 For each loop to skip first iteration. I have gone through previous answers in Stack Overflow. But all were Java <8 versions.

```
cars.forEach(car->{
//Skip first then do some thing
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cars.stream()
    .skip(1)
    .forEachOrdered...
```

*Or*:

```
Spliterator<Car> sp = cars.stream().spliterator();
sp.tryAdvance(x -> {
    // do nothing 
});

sp.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I have never used Stream yet. any limitations on using  strems?.. I mean to ask any issues if I use stream to Iterate over list of lists?

Comment: @GarrySteve there are plenty of advantages and there are limitations too, it all *depends*

Answer (score 4):

Other way is use `subList` method

```
cars.subList(1,cars.size()).forEach() ...
```